# How to copy files using for loop in command prompt

Tags: loops, for-loop, vbscript, command-prompt

I'm trying to copy files using command prompt in VBScript. The problem is with the double quotes in delims.

How do I fix this?

```
Dim oShell
Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")    
oShell.run "cmd /k mkdir .\my_Files\ & for /f **"delims="** %%A in (dir /s /b /ta C:\users\desktop\) do (copy '%%A' .\my_Files\)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use "" (double double quotes) to escape " in VBScript string literals:

```
>> cmd = "cmd /k mkdir .\my_Files\ & for /f **"delims="** %%A in (dir /s /b /ta C:\users\desktop\) do (copy '%
%A' .\my_Files\)"
>>
Error Number:       1025
Error Description:  Expected end of statement
>> cmd = "cmd /k mkdir .\my_Files\ & for /f **""delims=""** %%A in (dir /s /b /ta  C:\users\desktop\) do (copy
'%%A' .\my_Files\)"
>>
>> WScript.Echo cmd
>>
cmd /k mkdir .\my_Files\ & for /f **"delims="** %%A in (dir /s /b /ta C:\users\desktop\) do (copy '%%A' .\my_F
iles\)
>>
```